# Set the value of a lwc combobox by the value of a property in an object stored in map

Tags: lightning-web-components

simplified JS to exemplify the issue:

```
class PicklistValue {

    @api value;

    constructor(nextStep){
        this.nextStep = nextStep;
        this.isUpdatable = false;
    }
}

export default class xxx extends LightningElement {


    picklists = {'Familia' : new PicklistValue('Product'),
                    'Product' : new PicklistValue('Motivo'),
                    'Motivo' : new PicklistValue('SubMot1'),
                    'SubMot1' : new PicklistValue('SubMot2'),
                    'SubMot2' : new PicklistValue(null)}
}
```

Let's say I want to set the combobox value as the .value property of a certain object contained within `picklists`. Like I do in this function :

```
updateComponentStatus(event){
        for(value in picklistNames.slice(picklistNames.indexOf(event.target.name)+1,-1)){
            if(!picklists[value].value){
                fetchPicklistOptions(value);
            }
            updateSelectedValues(picklistName);
            unlockNextOptionAsUpdatable(value);
        }
    }
```

If I try to assign values in the html like this :

```
value={picklists['Family'].value}
value={picklist[family].value // asuming a declared variable family = 'Family';
```

Both are incorrect, got following errors for each, respectively

> LWC1058: Invalid HTML syntax:
> unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value. For more
> information, please visit
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-unexpected-character-in-unquoted-attribute-value
> (23:58)
>
> Invalid expression {picklists[family].value} - LWC1038: Template
> expression doesn't allow computed property access (23:41)

How can I do so?

Comment: have you tried using a [getter method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_props_getters_setters) on your controller? I think computed expression are not allowed, as explained: _To compute a value for the property, use a JavaScript getter in the JavaScript class, get property(){}_

Comment: The issue is that I want to use this dynamically , I need to re-use this method for the 4 different types but don't want to duplicate code on the js. And using a getter I would still run into the same issue right? I would have to implement a different getter for each picklist

Comment: I think one way you can do this is having the 4 getter methods (one for each picklist), and leverage all the logic in one [lib/helper function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code), the function could take one parameter so you can determine what getter method you are calling it from, and return the value based on that parameter. I don't know, maybe there are more efficient ways to do it, but you can give it a try.

Comment: This question is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What you're trying to do isn't possible, as there is no dynamic access feature in LWC. However, there may be a way to do what you're trying to do, yet I can't quite visualize the X (the original problem you're trying to solve). Can you include the code that led you to this "solution"?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to avoid duplicity in code in the js file by having a dynamic function to get some values stored in objects in a map. 
This way from the html i just want to use this function to access those values. 
However as you said, there is no dynamic access. Therefore as McCubo said the only way would be to program 4 getters as far as I understand. 
I added the function that assigns the values tor provide extra information on the question.